# iOS Facebook SDK - Manually Expire a Session - Kiosk App

Tags: ios, facebook, session, sdk, kiosk

I'm struggling with the darn Facebook SDK.

I'm writing a 'kiosk app' i.e. an App that will have multiple users use it throughout the course of a day - each user can optionally send info unto their Facebook accounts ( and I need to use the Graph API so I can't use ShareKit ), and then I need to get them to manually logout or it will do so automatically after a short timeout.

In either case it MUST forget their credentials and session data, so that when the next user ( even just moments after ) presses the Facebook button it won't try and use the previous users credentials and log automatically into the wrong account.

I'm even manually calling '[facebook logout:self];' and that NEVER does anything.

Please, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call auth.expireSession on the REST API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.expireSession/

I recently had to this for a kiosk app at f8. Nothing exist from the graph API yet to do this.